# c++11 Map ptrs of objects, fast/cached search

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, caching

I've a class to map many objects:

```
struct array:
    String       name;
    Parameter*   parameter;
    Slider*      slider;
    Label*       label;
```

The class has this methods:

```
 int getIndex (Label* label);
 int getIndex (Parameter* param);
 int getIndex (Slider* slider);
 int getIndex (String* name);
```

The I use in this way:

```
int index = map.getIndex (&slider);
Parameter* param = map.getParameter (index);

//------- or:

int index = map.getIndex (&label);
Slider* slider = map.getSlider (index);
```

The problem is that getIndex (ptr) has a for loop that iterates all elements in the "struct array" and compares by "structArray[i].slider == sliderPtr"

Any recommendations for avoiding walk the whole array? a cache system?
Thanks!

Comment: What is `structArray` supposed to be? The first code block is syntactically wrong. Although I can guess what you mean you should use correct syntax in questions. How is `map` declared? What does `getIndex` do? Thats not clear to me. You never defined `sliderPtr`, `getSlider`, `getParameter` etc. either.

Comment: Concerning the actual question as far as I can interpret it: The best data structure to use depends heavily on your access pattern of elements.